# Need help Understanding Linq group by with joins

Tags: linq

Hi I created this Linq query

```
  var k = from account in _session.All<AccountDetail>()
                join subscriber in _session.All<Subscriber>() on account.ID equals subscriber.AccID
                join subscriberServices in _session.All<SubscriberServce>() on subscriber.ID equals subscriberServices.UserID
                join paymentMethod in _session.All<PaymentMethod>() on subscriberServices.PaymentMethod_ID equals paymentMethod.ID
                join paymentFrequency in _session.All<PaymentFrequency>() on subscriberServices.PaymentFrequency_ID equals paymentFrequency.ID
                group account by new {AccID= account.ID,paymentFrequency= paymentFrequency.Description,paymentMethod= paymentMethod.Description} into G
                select new GenerateInvoiceData() { AccID = G.Key.AccID};
```

I don't understand

```
group account by new {AccID= account.ID,paymentFrequency= paymentFrequency.Description,paymentMethod= paymentMethod.Description} into G
```

why do I specify `account` when I'm not restricted to it in the anonymous type i.e. I can type paymentFrequency.Description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `group account` part is saying what you want the *elements* in each group to be. The `by new { ... }` is what you want the *key* for each group to be. That's not restricted to being part of the information in an element.

As a simplest example, you might have:

```
from person in people
group person.FirstName by person.LastName
```

which would give you groups where the key of each group was the last name of all the people represented in the group, and each element of each group would be the first name of someone.

You might want to read two of my Edulinq blog posts:

- [How query expressions work](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx)
- [The `GroupBy` method](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-21-groupby.aspx)